# Blackberry ApplicationIndicator click handler on Home Screen

Tags: blackberry, notifications, message

I am creating an application which has a notification icon on the status bar of the BlackBerry home screen.  I want to launch my app when this notification icon is clicked.

I am able to create a notification icon in the status bar with ApplicationIndicator, but I am not able to register a click handler to launch the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blackberry OS 6.0 we have a new API which can be used for launching an app from the notification bar. Here is an example:

```
try {
    DemoMessage msg = new DemoMessage();
    ApplicationDescriptor daemonDescr = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
    ApplicationDescriptor mainDescr = new ApplicationDescriptor(daemonDescr, "MyAppName", new String[] {});

    // Get existing messages from storage and register them in folders
    ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig inboxIntegration = new ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig(true, true, mainDescr);

    ApplicationMessageFolder folder = ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().registerFolder(
        APPLICATION_ID, "MyApplictionFolderName", new ReadableListImpl(),inboxIntegration);
    folder.fireElementAdded(msg);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where `DemoMessage` and `ReadableListimpl` are classes from Blackberry 6.0's `MessageListDemo` sample app.

For reference, see also this related question: [Opening application from notification bar in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967126/opening-application-from-notification-bar-in-blackberry).