# Opening application from notification bar in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, notifications, message

For my application I need to creat an icon in notification bar.I am able to do this.
My problem is I need to open this application from notification bar.
 When ever user selects notification screen my app status should display. when user selects my app my application should open directly.

Comment: To be fair, OP didn't get any answers for most of those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following classes:

```
ApplicationMessageFolder
ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry
```

And the following interfaces:

```
ApplicationMessage
ApplicationMessageFolderListener
```

Register a folder for your app, add a listener to the folder, and use the `AppicationMessageFolder.fireElementAdded()` method to add status messages to the folder.  When the user clicks on the notification bar, the Messages app displays the available folders and their contents.  When the user clicks on one of your status messages, the folder's listener will notify your app so it can react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I am able to open application from notification icon. while clicking my notification icon.. notification list field is coming with unread message count like .... MyAppName(1 unread).. Is it possible to Remove (1 unread) from the label.