# Blackberry - open application on message notification click

Tags: blackberry, notifications, message

My app sending messages notification to the home screen notification bar, but when I'm clicking on some message there, "Message Preview" window opens.

I am aware of
[SO - Opening application from notification bar in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967126/opening-application-from-notification-bar-in-blackberry)
[SO - Blackberry ApplicationIndicator click handler on Home Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044527/blackberry-applicationindicator-click-handler-on-home-screen)

While I have implemented [ApplicationMessageFolderListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationMessageFolderListener.html) and adding it to [ApplicationMessageFolder](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationMessageFolder.html), still [actionPerformed](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationMessageFolderListener.html#actionPerformed%28int,%20net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessage%5B%5D,%20net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessageFolder%29) is never called when I'm clicking on message in notification bar.

Is there a way to handle notification message click event from own application?

Same question [on BB forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Open-application-on-mesage-notification-click/td-p/1462147).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently struggled with this very same problem.  When a user opens an `ApplicationMessage` object, `ApplicationMessageFolderListener.actionPerformed()` is not notified.  It is notified if the user marks the message as opened without actually opening it.  After some digging, this is by design.

To get notified when the message is actually opened, you have to implement a class that extends the `ApplicationMenuItem` class and overrides its `run()` method.  The `context` parameter will be set to the `ApplicationMessage` object that is being opened.  You can then register that menu item using the `ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.registerMessageMenuItems()` method for the particular message state combinations that the menu item applies to, such as `ApplicationMessage.Status.UNOPENED`.

Comment: I have registered the menuItems but the applicationMessage do not opens anymore. Please take a look at: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995593/blackberry-use-of-applicationmenuitem-when-opening-a-message" and an answer will be really helpful for me. Thanks.