# Blackberry - listen when applicationMessage is opened

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to know when the user opens a message from the notification area (opened from the home screen - clicked on the app notification icon) thrown by my app.

`ApplicationMessageFolderListener` do not work for this and registering an applicationMenuItem cause the message to not open anymore (see [Blackberry - use of ApplicationMenuItem when opening a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995593/blackberry-use-of-applicationmenuitem-when-opening-a-message)).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: ApplicationMessageFolderListener is being implemented? and the the actionPerformed method added?

Comment: yes, it's implemented, but is called just once  with MARK_OLD action and with empty array of messages. See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536271/blackberry-open-application-on-mesage-notification-click"   - "hen a user opens an ApplicationMessage object, ApplicationMessageFolderListener.actionPerformed() is not notified. It is notified if the user marks the message as opened without actually opening it. After some digging, this is by design"

Answer (score 0):

The below code should be of some help:

```
ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry registry =
    ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance();
ApplicationMessageFolder inbox = 
    registry.getApplicationFolder(MessageListHelper.YOUR_CUSTOM_INBOX_FOLDER_ID);
ApplicationDescriptor daemonDescr = 
    ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
```

Get existing messages from storage and register them in folders.

```
MessageStore messages = MessageListHelper.getMessageStore();
ApplicationMessageFolder inbox =
   registry.registerFolder(MessageListHelper.YOUR_CUSTOM_INBOX_FOLDER_ID, 
   "Inbox", messages.getInboxMessages());
```

Register ourselves as a listener for callback notifications.

```
inbox.addListener(this, ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_DELETED |
   ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_OPENED |
   ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_UNOPENED, daemonDescr);
messages.setFolders(inbox);
registry.setRootFolderName(MessageListHelper.ROOT_FOLDER_NAME);
```

i just get the feeling while adding listener to the inbox, you may be missing out on the the options you are setting like

```
ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_DELETED | 
ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_OPENED | 
ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_UNOPENED
```

so, `actionPerformed()` is getting called only for the first time to mark it old or something.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it won't work for me. When opening the message, the listener is not called. If I delete the message, then it is called.

Comment: applicationMessageFolder.addListener(alarmsMessageFolderListener, 
      ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_DELETED | 
      ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_OPENED | 
      ApplicationMessageFolderListener.MESSAGE_MARKED_UNOPENED, daemonDescr);